# Как работает switch "под капотом"?

Tags: c++, switch

Недавно стало интересно, как работает switch в С++. Вычитал что существует таблица переходов, но она в некоторых случаях создается, а в некоторых - нет, вообщем до конца не понятно, что да как. Не могли бы вы разъяснить про реализацию этого прекрасного оператора в С++. Заранее спасибо :)

Comment: *Может существовать*.  Посмотрите https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/re7hE7MYr, потом добавьте оптимизацию `-O2` и посмотрите еще раз https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6E9EzPs14...

Comment: Реализация зависит от компилятора. Занудство: statement, а не оператор.

Comment: [Something You May Not Know About the Switch Statement in C/C++](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/100473/Something-You-May-Not-Know-About-the-Switch-Statem)